# Can we get device tracking data in salesforce marketing cloud even though the email is not engaged in

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, sfmc-business-unit

Basically, I want to extract Device/OS/EmailClient level information on Email Deliveries.

I am aware that, We can fetch this information using data extract activity and other reporting options AFTER THE EMAIL IS OPENED/CLICKED, but I want to extract device information for all email deliveries (including non-engagers).

EXAMPLE: Consider an scenario where an email delivered to 5000 users, out of which 1000 users are opened/clicked. I can able to fetch device level data for those 1000 engaged users, but not for remaining 4000 delivered users

Is there any option in SFMC to extract device/OS level information for email deliveries.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! I don't know the answer to your question, but I sure hope that it is "No!"

Comment: How do you imagine this being done? E.g. my Gmail account is regularly accessed on: 1: my Gmail app on iPhone, 2: on Gmail.com, 3: in Mail on OS X. When the email is delivered, which client should then be shown? There is a good and logical reason for, why the client information is being provided only on opens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical handshake to ascertain whether an email has been delivered, or where it ended up (junk, inbox, gmail promotions tab...).

for reference: For opening tracking, an opening tracking pixel (1x1 px sized image) is loaded when someone (a device) loads the images in an email (yes, pre-caching exists, but that IS the opening pixel being loaded), and the server hosting the image reads out the device information from the device accessing the image.

There is no "arrival pixel" that would be similar to an opening pixel, but loaded once a client inbox receives the mail. As stated by Lukas in the comments, it would also not make sense, as "reaching the inbox" has nothing to do with the device(s) used. If it's there, it's usually on, say, a gmail webserver, and you can view it from many devices simultaneously.

So: the sending server normally gets no response back from the probable recipient (like when loading the opening pixel graphic), from which it could read out any client-side data.

It is usually inferred by the lack of a bounce response that the email reached an inbox.

In short: Since we do not even know for sure IF it arrived at all, we also have no idea on anything contextual, like device etc.